# HTML + CSS - Making an Image Element a Parent?

Tags: html, css, position, element, parent

I know this may seem like a newby question, but is it possible to set an image element as a parent? If so, how can I do so?

Heres an example of what I'm looking for:

[image: Example]

Also, the reason I can't just have the div element as the parent is that I want that text element relative to that image element, not the div element. This way I can center the text relative to the image. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Why not put the `img` on another `div` with 100% width? Then make the text relative to that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've figured it out. I started messing with some values and I got it.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-div">
    <img id="image" src="url.com/image.png">
    <h1 id="text">Caption</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  text-align: center;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  display: block;
  border: thin red solid;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle of the code and final result: https://jsfiddle.net/k3b70Lg7/

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot because image elements are replaced.

You can however wrap the image and the text element in another `div` and position that.

```
<div class="outer-black">
   <div class="inner-image-text-wrapper">
       <img src="..">
       <div class="text"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now setting the wrapper to be inline-text means that it will expand according to contents (*the image*) and by setting it also to be `position:relative` you can position the text (*`position:absolute`*) wherever you want inside it.

---

Full example

```css
.outer-black {
  background: black;
  padding: 2em;
}
.inner-image-text-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.inner-image-text-wrapper img{display:block;}
.inner-image-text-wrapper .text{
  position:absolute;
  top:105%;
  left:5%;
  right:5%;
  text-align:center;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-black">
  <div class="inner-image-text-wrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/300/200/1">
    <div class="text">image caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @APixelVisuals did you see the demo i posted with the relevant css ? the text is positioned relative to the image since the wrapper is sized only by the image. If you describe better the final result you want we can give more relevant suggestions.

Comment: yeah I saw the demo, I think I'm doing something wrong I'll keep trying and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: alright heres what I have:

HTML:
<div id="home-stats">

        <div class="this-div">
          <img class="image" src="Images/Enable Disable.png">
          <h1 class="text">Caption Here</h1>
        </div>

      </div>

Comment: CSS:
.this-div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 500px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  display: block;
  border: thin red solid;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 15%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: translate(-15%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  text-align: center;
  border: thin red solid;
}

Comment: @APixelVisuals looks fine to me. the text is always inside the image. What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: My goal is the image I added to the original question and what I have currently is this: https://gyazo.com/156a332b5e367f751f949d43f614eb57 the issue is that the text still isn't centered

Comment: @APixelVisuals updated the CSS in my answer check if it what you want.

Comment: hmmm no not quite the text still isn't centered, here's a JS Fiddle of my code to show you what I'm getting as a result https://jsfiddle.net/6frym12t/

Comment: @APixelVisuals the idea is that you do not move the `img` element. What ever you want to happen to the whole image/text group you apply to the wrapper element. Then to center the text use `left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);` See https://jsfiddle.net/6frym12t/2/

Comment: oh I was just posting about that same fix haha! Check out the post I made here to see what I did. Thanks so much :)